# Small keyboard in landscape

Tags: keyboard, swype

I love Swype, but it has one big problem: it's almost impossible to use in landscape on a 5-inch screen. It just gets difficult to run my finger correctly across the keyboard when it's spread out across the entire screen.

**Is there a way to restrict the width of swype (or virtual keyboards in general) when in landscape mode?** I just want it to retain the standard layout of the portrait keyboard.

Running a fully rooted and customizable Nexus 4.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question. I don't think it's possible in general, but I don't know about Swype in particular.

Comment: @DanHulme I'm pretty sure swype has no option of this sort, that's why I was asking about keyboards in general. I was hoping there might be some hack that forces the keyboard to stay in portrait even if the device is in landscape. But it was just a shot in the dark anyway. =/

Comment: SwiftKey has this feature nowadays, and supports gesture typing like Swype.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in Swype to change the size (width) of the keyboard, and shrink it. Press-hold on the Symbols key ("?123"). There will be options to change the keyboard size. Drag your finger to the icon showing the size you may want (on the left side, right side, floating...).